# OpenGL ES 2.0 artifacts/dithering in FBO on Mali-400

Tags: android, opengl-es, fbo, mali-400

When rendering to a frame buffer object in gles 2.0 I have some strange artifacts on the Mali-400 gpu. Problem is that some pixels have different colors than others even if I fill the whole screen with the same color. But it works fine on a Tegra2 gpu. Does the Mali use any texture compression by default? My fbo uses GL_RGBA as internal format. 
Thanks in advance!

----Edit----
I guess I solved my own question. The problem was simply that GL_DITHER was enabled by default on the Mali, while is seems that it was not on the Tegra. A simple glDisable(GL_DITHER) solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have been struggling around with the same problem and setting GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DITHER); finally solved it.